# Any way a Python program can interact with a particular tab from user browser using Selenium? NOT CHROMEDRIVER BUT ACTUAL CHROME BROWSER

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, automation, automated-tests

Ok so, imagine that I'm a Windows user who currently has open his chrome browser with the following tabs sorted as shown:

1. [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/)
2. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
3. [Google](https://www.google.com/)

I'm interested in using a Python program that first reads every single tab I currently have open in my chrome browser (**not the chromedriver**), looks for the [Google](https://www.google.com/) one if it exists, and type in the Google search bar

> This program works fine

And then press `Enter`

The final outcome should be something like this:

[image: Pre final step]

[image: Final step]

If possible, how could the final outcome above be achieved?